# Changing Input Text Value JS

Tags: javascript, html, square

Breadit here and I have a problem. I tried to look everywhere but can't find a single answer that will work. I am trying to make a button which will square the first  tag and will print the output on the second  tag.

JavaScript:

```
function square() {
    var a=document.getElementById("inputSquare");
    var b=a*a;
    document.getElementById("outputSquare").value=b;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="number" id="inputSquare">
<button onclick="square()">=</button>
<input type="number" id="outputSquare" readonly>
```

That is my problem.

Comment: You need value, not element it self, for var a....

Comment: Let's see, I'm sure you fired up the debugger and walked through this step by step, right? So you placed a breakpoint on the `var b=a*a` line, and there you examined the value of `a`, and/or tried typing `a*a` into the console to see what it evaluated to, right? Anyway, you say "That is my problem", but we don't know what your problem is--what is it? What does this code do, vs. what do you want it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function squaree() {
    var a=document.getElementById("inputSquare").value;
    var b=a*a;
    document.getElementById("outputSquare").value=b;
}
```

Also. you have to put the code in `<script>` tag inside head. Not in dom load or jquery ready function. Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/q7oms4nh/

Comment: Was the function name supposed to be "squaree" or was it just a typo?

Comment: squaree is a typo. Would work fine if you rename it. the .value is missing from the second line in the javascript. Happy to see it worked for you.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

need to have `var a = document.getElementById("inputSquare").value`

EDIT: What nevermind said.